# Street view google map URL and coordinate query

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-street-view

I am currently converting a number of simple Google Map Street View links into URL requests for static Street View images.  Most of the conversions work except for a few odd instances which I am struggling to explain.

Firstly, in the normal way, I access Google Maps as a regular user and find the position on a road in London I want to see called London Wall, and I point upwards and eastwards.  This is the resulting link: (please test it and you will see a prominent building called Winchester House with a smooth curved exterior in the flash Street View used by Google consumers):

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Winchester+House,+London+Wall,+London,+United+Kingdom&hl=en&ll=51.516287,-0.083299&spn=0.007838,0.018196&sll=51.522309,-0.080509&sspn=0.06227,0.145569&oq=winchester+house,+london+wall&hq=Winchester+House,&hnear=Wall,+1+Denbigh+Rd,+London+W11+2SJ,+United+Kingdom&t=m&z=16&layer=c&cbll=51.516305,-0.083422&panoid=U6g4EoZt5cM4e2WFiDLoxA&cbp=12,268.2,,0,-16.66

Secondly, if I adopt the same coordinates from the above link to get a Static Street View Photo via the following URL request, I get a different result:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=800x600&location=51.516305,%20-0.083422&fov=110&heading=268.2&pitch=16.66&sensor=false

This second view is still looking westwards along London wall, but the Static Street View photo is set approximately 50+ metres on the wrong global coordinate (please try the link above and you will see a footbridge is in front of Winchester House, which lies in the distance).

This is confusing when both URLs above appear to be using the same global coordinates. (I have referenced the same coordinates for many other different links and both URLs usually show the same view).

I would be grateful for anyone's help on this and understand whether anyone has experienced similar problems or inconsistencies with different Google coordinates.

Many thanks

Mike

Comment: the 2 URLs above now generates the correct images